# Why does Popen hang when used in Django view?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, web

In one of my Django views, I need to start an asynchronous job that may take minutes to finish. Since Celery+message queue would be an overkill for this task, I used subprocess.Popen to create a subprocess, like this:

```
args = ['python', SCRIPT_PATH, "&"];
try:
    subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) # Async call
except:
    pass
return HttpResponse("Job submitted")
```

I used nginx+gunicorn to run my django application. When I start the server and leave the shell session open, the above code works fine.
But when I close the shell session, the code stops working and hangs in the Popen line.

I guess it is about the stdout/stderr arguments, but I don't know how to change that to make this work.

=========EDIT===========

This is what I do in the script: I used selenium webdriver+phantomjs to load a web page and submit a form, in this process, selenium or phantomjs writes to standard output or standard error. When I start gunicorn in a shell, and later close the shell session, selenium or phantom 's write fails.
When I start gunicorn with its output redirect to a file like this:

```
gunicorn app.wsgi > /tmp/gunicorn.log &
```

the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

While I cannot ascertain the reason for the Popen line blocking with the details that you have given, I can suggest an alternative. Also, I am not sure you need the "&" option as well.

You can use NamedTemporaryFiles for the stdout and stderr error streams like this

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
output = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
error = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
Popen(args, stdout=output, stderr=error)
```

This does not block. I presume you already have taken care of what is to be done when Popen finishes.

The Popen docs have a warning regarding PIPE objects. I am pasting it here for completeness

`The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.`